# Getting the Thévenin equivalent resistance for a max power problem

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, thevenin

The given question : 
[image]

I went on to get Rth by adding a voltage of 1v to control the dependent source from which I obtain the current in the branches and get the total current , as follow then later decide it by 1 since 1/I =v by ohms law to get Rth:

[image]

But in the the answer of the text book I’m using ((fundamentals of electric circuits 5th ed chapter 4 practical problem 13)) , no 1v voltage (or current ) were introduced and he solved as : 
[image]
[image]

Which I found very confusing.

So the bottom line is : 
When and when not are voltage sources introduced in the analysis to get Rth when there’s a dependent source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the bottom line is : When and when not are voltage sources introduced in the analysis to get Rth when there’s a dependent source ?

Both should work. As a summary, you can find the \$R_{TH}\$ by doing one of the following:

**Option 1:** If all the sources in your circuit are independent (not in this case since there is a dependent one), you just deactivate them and find the equivalent resistance of the network you are left with. By deactivating, voltage sources become shorts, and current sources become open circuits.

**Option 2:** You can find the short circuit current, (\$I_{sc}\$), flowing through the terminals of interest and to find \$R_{TH}\$, you compute \$R_{TH}=\dfrac{V_{TH}}{I_{sc}}\$. In this case, you don't deactivate any of the sources.

**Option 3:** This is what you are doing, but you are making a mistake. You add a test source across the terminals of interest, but ***you have to deactivate the independent sources, and leave the dependent ones untouched***. So, in your method, you need to make the 9V source a short circuit (0V).

Both option 2 and 3 should give you the right result.

Comment: It worked but is there an explaintion for case 3?

Comment: @sarah I think this may help (look at the accepted answer): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308890/why-are-dependent-sources-not-disabled-with-the-superposition-principle

Answer (score 1):

People often forget that superposition theorem also applies with dependent sources as demonstrated in several [papers](http://www.dei.unipd.it/~pel/Compl_Elettr_I/PDF/superpos.pdf). It truly helps in some cases like in this one with a controlled source. The first thing is to start with the control variable, \$v_x\$ in this example. Using the labels I associate in the below sketch, a few lines get you there:

\$v_x=R_1\frac{V_1-3v_x}{R_1+R_2}\$ and solving for \$v_x\$ leads to \$v_x=\frac{R_1V_1}{4R_1+R_2}=2\;V\$ with \$V_1=9\;V\$. Now that you have the control variable, apply superposition by letting \$V_1\$ be 0 V (replace it by a short) and you are left with the \$3v_x\$ source with the \$v_x\$ we have determined. You calculate \$V_{o1}\$. Then, reduce to 0 V the \$3v_x\$ source and calculate \$V_{o2}\$. Summing up both results lead you to \$V_th\$. If everything goes well, you should find \$V_{th}=\frac{V_1(3R_1+R_2)}{4R_1+R_2}=7\;V\$. A quick sim confirms this result:

[image]

For the Thévenin resistance, short the output and determine the short-circuit current. You may calculate the 3 currents and determine in this configuration the voltage \$v_x\$ which is equal to \$v_x=\frac{R_1V_o(R_2+R_3)}{3R_1R_3+R_2R_3}\$. \$V_0\$ is the voltage at the resistances junction and is defined as \$V_0=V_1-v_x\$. Replacing \$v_x\$ by its definition and solving for \$V_o\$ gives the final short-circuit current equal to \$I_{sc}=\frac{V_o}{R_3}=1.658\;A\$. The Thévenin resistance is then defined as \$R_{th}=\frac{V_{th}}{I_{sc}}=\frac{7}{1.658}=4.222\;\Omega\$. A quick sim will let you know if this final value is ok; install a 1-A current source and ask the simulator to determine the transfer function from node 4 to the 1-A source:

[image]

The simulator gives you:

***** SMALL SIGNAL DC TRANSFER FUNCTION

```
output_impedance_at_V(4)        4.222222e+000
i1#Input_impedance      4.222222e+000
Transfer_function       4.222222e+000
```

which is what we found. Trying to simplify these problems by breaking them into small pieces is the divide and conquer method promoted by the [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371). Learn how they work and solve transfer functions in a swift and efficient manner. The below Mathcad sheet summarizes the calculations:

[image]