# Dependent sources removal

Tags: thevenin

In thevenin's and norton's theorem why do we dont remove the dependent sources in calculating the thevenin's resistance. And secondly,why do we only use 1 ampere/1 volt source to find the thevenin's resistance when there is a dependent source?

Comment: Read here https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/finding-thevenin-norton-impedence-in-a-circuit-with-dependent-source.104152/#post-789013  and this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308890/why-are-dependent-sources-not-disabled-with-the-superposition-principle

Answer (score 1):

Independent sources do not affect the Thevenin resistance because their value is fixed. Voltage sources have fixed voltage and a variable current. Current sources have a fixed current and variable voltage. In a linear system, this fixed value only affects the zero crossing and not the slope. The slope is the resistance.

With dependant sources, both values are variable, current and voltage, for all the different varieties of the dependent sources. In a linear system, this will affect the slope and intern the resistance of the system.

A unit of 1 amp/volt is used just to make the calculation easier. Anyone can divide or multiply by 1.