# Source Transformation on Dependent Current Source

Tags: nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

[image]

I am facing issues while finding Vr3(V1) I have redrawn the circuit with circuit being open at current source I1 and have source transformed the dependent current source to a dependent voltage source in series with the resistor. However, the value I am getting after solving using mesh analysis is different from the one I am getting using nodal analysis without source transformation. I do agree nodal analysis is a pretty elegant method over here, but I wanted to know as to why source transformation over here is getting me a different answer.

Attempt to Solve using source transformation
Right answer is 22.5V

[image]

Comment: It is had to say because you did not show us your work. Also, shouldn't you use the superposition only? And I do not know if such source transformation is allowed in this case because you wanted to find VR3 voltage.

Comment: I have the same doubt and wanted to know why if it is not allowed, I have attached my work.

Comment: are you saying that \$ V_{R_3} (V_1) = 22.5 V \$ is the correct answer from ur book?

Comment: For me, such a transformation is not allowed because the voltage and the current will be different.  Take a look at this example https://tinyurl.com/yuag3lrg

Comment: @G36 Why is that? after you made a transformation to voltage current you get \$100V = 31.667 V + V_x \$ with \$V_x \$ that parallel branch that we replaced, you get the exact answer, no?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI The answer (Vx) is the same for the rest of a circuit not. But not for the voltage across R3 resistor. And why OP thinks that he needs to do this type of transformation is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

This question can easily be solved using the superposition theorem despite the fact that some people say that it is impossible due to the dependent source present in the circuit.
The circuit in question
[image]

First, we turn off all of the sources except \$I_1\$.

We are left with this circuit:

[image]

And we can use the current divider rule.

$$V_{R3}(1) = I_1 \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} * R_3 = 40V$$

And the "control" current is:

$$i(1)= I_1 \frac{R_2 + R_3}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} =  \frac{8}{3} \:[A] \approx 2.666 \:A $$

Next, we turn off \$I_1\$ and turn on \$V_1\$

[image]

$$V_{R3}(2) = V_1 \frac{R_3}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} = 30V$$

And the "control" current

$$i(2) = -\frac{V_1}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} = -1A $$

So now we turn off all the sources except CCCS.

[image]

And again the current divider rule in action.

$$V_{R3}(3) = I_d \frac{R_1 + R_2}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} * R_3 = $$
$$V_{R3}(3) = 0.4i*0.5*30\Omega = 6i$$

So we need to know the "control" current first.

$$i(3) = I_d * \frac{R_3}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} = 0.2i $$
$$i(3) = 0.4i * 0.5 = 0.2i $$

Therefore, the "control" current is equal to:

$$i = i(1) + i(2) + i(3)$$

$$i = \frac{8}{3}- 1 + 0.2i$$

$$i = \frac{5}{3} + 0.2i$$

$$0.8i = \frac{5}{3}$$

$$i = \frac{5}{3} * \frac{10}{8} = \frac{50}{24}  \:[A] \approx 2.0833A$$

So,

$$V_{R3}(3) = 6i = \frac{300}{24} \: [V] = 12.5V$$

Therefore, \$V_{R3}\$ voltage is:

$$V_{R3} = V_{R3}(1)+V_{R3}(2)+V_{R3}(3) = 40V + 30V + 12.5V = 82.5V$$

The END.

Comment: wait... how do you power-suply a dependent device? do you not realise that i = 0? or am I missing a concept in superposition?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI What?  Can you elaborate more? Because I don't understand what you were trying to say.

Comment: if you have a current dependent source how do you remove ALL the other main sources and leave it alone, my question is what is the source that power suplies the resistance \$ R_1 \$ ?

Comment: Superposition can be applied to the circuit with dependent sources. Take a look at this example and the videos https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308890/why-are-dependent-sources-not-disabled-with-the-superposition-principle/308903#308903